# USB memory stick not working any more

Tags: usb-drive

I have one USB memory stick (FAT32) that I was using on Ubuntu. However, recently it does not mount when I put it into the USB port. Application "Disks" does not recognize it at all. However, when I start Windows, I can access my data and use this stick normally. Stick is 8 GB of size. When was under Windows, I preformed disk checkup, and everything is fine with the stick. But sticks does not work any more on Ubuntu.

Other sticks are still working normally on Ubuntu (I have one with 4 GB, and another of 2 GB).

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x943c943c

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   312560639   156280288+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       312561662   625141759   156290049    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       617332736   625141759     3904512   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       312561664   617332735   152385536   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

---

After some period of time (about 5 minutes of waiting) `sudo fisk -l` provided additional lines:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 8074 MB, 8074035200 bytes
39 heads, 31 sectors/track, 13043 cylinders, total 15769600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x04030201

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2056    15769599     7883772    b  W95 FAT32
```

---

In order to open it again, I need to type this command and wait...

Comment: What is the output of `sudo fdisk -l` when your USB stick is connected?

Comment: I edited my previous post to include the output of this command.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

connect the USB memory stick

open a terminal and type `sudo fdisk -l` and wait until it finishes (the five minutes you're talking about).

when the "$" sign (and all the text behind it) shows up again type those in the terminal:

`sudo mkdir /media/anything`

then (when "$" comes again)

`sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/anything -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137`

this should solve your problem!

...ofcourse you can replace the word "anything" by any word you like but be careful not to use spaces and to use the same word in both commands.

you can also look this up: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#

Comment: thanks... but memory stick started to work again... by itself :) Kingston... I updated to new version of Ubuntu (13.10) and I don't have problem any more.

Comment: okay that's great! :D congrats :D

Comment: but this does not change the fact that it was not working :) (while under windows it does)

Comment: are you intentionally comparing ubuntu to windows because you want to say that windows is better? >:D

Comment: :) no, those are not my intentions...I still prefer Ubuntu and I find it not only free, but better OS than Windows... I am experienced user and such problems occur on any system (including the Windows), but I was trying to discover what could be the cause of my problems :)

Comment: hahahahahaha looks like I'm the bad guy here XD

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with one of my memory sticks.  I installed `pmount`

```
sudo apt-get install pmount
```

and then mounted it with

```
pmount /dev/stb1
```

and I was then able to use the stick.

Comment: -1 The issue is not, that OP doesn't know how to mount a USB drive, but that the USB drive behaves weirdly before even reaching a point, where it could be mounted.